# How to record screen video with speaker's speech - Windows 10

Tags: windows, video-recording

I've been trying to record a video like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpPG0bKHYKc) for about a whole day already. I've tried out EzVid, VLC, but nothing helps.
EzVid does not record my voice for some reason, while VLC crashes just after being downloaded. With Windows 10 XBOX video recorder, I will have to record my voice separately which is unacceptable.

Any ideas is there any app which can be used smoothly on Windows 10 ?

Comment: This is a question about general computing hardware and software and belongs at SuperUser.com. They have the same dislike for software recommendations as we do, though. You might want to try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the creator of that video you linked in your original post is using Camtasia. I've also used this in the past and is what I'd recommend using.

You can get a free trial of Camtasia from their website, but I believe after a certain amount of days you need to purchase the software.https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html

Other than that, I was going to recommend Fraps as you can capture audio recordings at the same time as video recording, but I believe with Windows 10 this doesn't work as I've tried this before.

Another piece of software I've heard of before but never used (so I can't comment on it) is OBS, which is free https://obsproject.com/ this can record audio/video, as well as stream to applications such as TwitchTV.